# T-SQL Use a column name as a parameter in a function used as default value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [Operating].[SalesDetails] (
    [BillId]       INT             NOT NULL,
    [SerialNumber] NVARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
    [Quantity]     INT             NOT NULL,
    [Price]        DECIMAL (19, 2) DEFAULT (IT.SalePrice([SerialNumber])) NOT NULL,
    [LineTotal]    AS              ([Quantity]*[Price]),
    [Returned]     BIT             DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [Note]         NVARCHAR (30)   NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Operating_SalesDetails_BillId_SerialNumber]
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BillId] ASC, [SerialNumber] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Operating_SalesDetails_Operating_Sales_BillId]
        FOREIGN KEY ([BillId]) REFERENCES [Operating].[Sales] ([BillId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Operating_SalesDetails_Operating_PurchasesDetails_SerialNumber]
        FOREIGN KEY ([SerialNumber])
        REFERENCES [Operating].[PurchasesDetails] ([SerialNumber]),
    CONSTRAINT [CK_Operating_SalesDetails_Price_Positive]
        CHECK ([Price]>=(0)),
    CONSTRAINT [CK_Operating_SalesDetails_Quantity_Positive]
        CHECK ([Quantity]>(0))
);
```

Function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [IT].[SalePrice] (@SerialNumber NVARCHAR (50)) RETURNS DECIMAL (19, 2)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SalePrice DECIMAL (19, 2)
    SET @SalePrice = (
        SELECT [Sale]
        FROM [Operating].[PurchasesDetails]
        WHERE [SerialNumber] = @SerialNumber
    )
    RETURN @SalePrice
END
```

This is the Purchases Details table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [Operating].[PurchasesDetails] (
    [BillId]         INT             NOT NULL,
    [ProductId]      INT             NOT NULL,
    [ManufacturerId] INT             NOT NULL,
    [SerialNumber]   NVARCHAR (50)   DEFAULT ([IT].[SerialNumber]()) NOT NULL,
    [Quantity]       INT             NOT NULL,
    [Purchase]       DECIMAL (19, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Sale]           DECIMAL (19, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Returned]       BIT             DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [Note]           NVARCHAR (30)   NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Operating_PurchasesDetails_SerialNumber]
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SerialNumber] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Operating_PurchasesDetails_Operating_Purchases_BillId]
        FOREIGN KEY ([BillId]) REFERENCES [Operating].[Purchases] ([BillId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Operating_PurchasesDetails_Operating_Products_ProductId]
        FOREIGN KEY ([ProductId]) REFERENCES [Operating].[Products] ([ProductId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Operating_PurchasesDetails_Operating_Manufacturers_ManufacturerId]
        FOREIGN KEY ([ManufacturerId])
        REFERENCES [Operating].[Manufacturers] ([ManufacturerId]),
    CONSTRAINT [CK_Operating_PurchasesDetails_Purchase_Positive]
        CHECK ([Purchase]>=(0)),
    CONSTRAINT [CK_Operating_PurchasesDetails_Quantity_Positive]
        CHECK ([Quantity]>(0)),
    CONSTRAINT [CK_Operating_PurchasesDetails_Sale_Positive]
        CHECK ([Sale]>=(0)),
    CONSTRAINT [CK_Operating_PurchasesDetails_SerialNumber_Quantity]
        CHECK ([Quantity]=(1) OR [Quantity]>(1)
        AND [SerialNumber] like 'NS[0-1][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
);
```

I get error `SQL70536` when I use `[SerialNumber]` as a parameter.

`SQL70536`: The name `“[SerialNumber]”` is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

Note: The function is tested and is working.

Please help.

Comment: Post the FULL error. Error "SQL70536" is not a SQL Server error.

Comment: Can you post the schema/structure of   [Operating].[PurchasesDetails]

Comment: If the function is tested and working, *when* are you getting that error? Also, please replace the image with text; errors are text after all. show us the SQL you are using to get said error.

Comment: What if you add the word select before the scalar function?

Comment: Then you get this message "Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed."

Comment: It's not the function that's the issue.  It's the DDL and the line "[Price]        DECIMAL (19, 2) DEFAULT (IT.SalePrice([SerialNumber])) NOT NULL,"

Comment: I know that SteveC, but what is the alternative???

Comment: You could default to a constant and then have a trigger look for the constant and then update with query

Comment: Why is the function's purpose not done by assignment upon insert?  Should we be looking at that?

Comment: Okay will try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eddited the trigger as suggested:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [Operating].[SalesDetails] (
    [BillId]       INT             NOT NULL,
    [SerialNumber] NVARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
    [Quantity]     INT             NOT NULL,
    [Price]        DECIMAL (19, 2) NOT NULL,
    [LineTotal]    AS              ([Quantity]*[Price]),
    [Returned]     BIT             DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [Note]         NVARCHAR (30)   NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Operating_SalesDetails_BillId_SerialNumber]
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BillId] ASC, [SerialNumber] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Operating_SalesDetails_Operating_Sales_BillId]
        FOREIGN KEY ([BillId]) REFERENCES [Operating].[Sales] ([BillId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Operating_SalesDetails_Operating_PurchasesDetails_SerialNumber]
        FOREIGN KEY ([SerialNumber])
        REFERENCES [Operating].[PurchasesDetails] ([SerialNumber]),
    CONSTRAINT [CK_Operating_SalesDetails_Price_Positive] CHECK ([Price]>=(0)),
    CONSTRAINT [CK_Operating_SalesDetails_Quantity_Positive] CHECK ([Quantity]>(0))
);
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [Operating].[SalePrice] ON [Operating].[SalesDetails]
    INSTEAD OF INSERT AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [Operating].[SalesDetails]
        ([BillId],[SerialNumber],[Quantity],[Price],[Returned],[Note])
    SELECT I.[BillId], I.[SerialNumber], I.[Quantity],
        COALESCE (I.[Price],P.[Sale]), I.[Returned], I.[Note]
    FROM [inserted] AS I LEFT OUTER JOIN [Operating].[PurchasesDetails] AS P
    ON I.[SerialNumber] = P.[SerialNumber]
END;
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

A trigger solved the problem. Thanks.

```sql
CREATE TABLE [Operating].[SalesDetails] (
    [BillId]       INT             NOT NULL,
    [SerialNumber] NVARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
    [Quantity]     INT             NOT NULL,
    [Price]        DECIMAL (19, 2) NOT NULL,
    [LineTotal]    AS              ([Quantity] * [Price]),
    [Returned]     BIT             DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [Note]         NVARCHAR (30)   NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Operating_SalesDetails_BillId_SerialNumber]
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BillId] ASC, [SerialNumber] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Operating_SalesDetails_Operating_Sales_BillId]
        FOREIGN KEY ([BillId]) REFERENCES [Operating].[Sales] ([BillId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Operating_SalesDetails_Operating_PurchasesDetails_SerialNumber]
        FOREIGN KEY ([SerialNumber])
        REFERENCES [Operating].[PurchasesDetails] ([SerialNumber]),
    CONSTRAINT [CK_Operating_SalesDetails_Price_Positive] CHECK ([Price] >= (0)),
    CONSTRAINT [CK_Operating_SalesDetails_Quantity_Positive] CHECK ([Quantity] > (0))
);
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [Operating].[SalePrice] ON [Operating].[SalesDetails]
    INSTEAD OF INSERT AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [Operating].[SalesDetails]
        ([BillId],[SerialNumber],[Quantity],[Price],[Returned],[Note])
    VALUES (
    (SELECT [BillId] FROM [INSERTED]),
    (SELECT [SerialNumber] FROM [INSERTED]),
    (SELECT [Quantity] FROM [INSERTED]),
    (SELECT [Sale] FROM [Operating].[PurchasesDetails]
        WHERE [SerialNumber] = (SELECT [SerialNumber] FROM [INSERTED])),
    (SELECT [Returned] FROM [INSERTED]),
    (SELECT [Note] FROM [INSERTED]))
END;
```

Is there a shorter way to write the trigger?

Comment: Your trigger is going to fail when more than one row is inserted at the same time.  Just a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: You want to `insert` from `inserted as I inner join [Operating].[PurchasesDetails] as PD on I.SerialNumber = PD.SerialNumber` to pick up the value of `Sale` for each row. If there might not be a match on `SerialNumber` then `left outer join` (rather than `inner join`) will provide a `NULL` for `Sale` rather than ignoring the `inserted` row.